# Are older Hasselblad H series cameras worth investing in?

Tags: medium-format, hasselblad

I have been looking at getting a medium format camera for a while, and I particularly want a Hasselblad (I know it's a brand thing).

What are the pros and cons of the V series (e.g. 503CW) vs the (older) H series (e.g. H1)?

So far I can think of the following points:

**H series:**
Pros:
 - Auto focus
 - data embedding onto film
 - get 16 shots on a roll of 120mm film

Cons: 
 - battery reliance 
 - expensive lenses
 - non-square/smaller image format
 - more electrics to go wrong

**V series:**
Pros:
- simple operation
- larger square frame
- lots of parts and lenses available a reasonable prices

Cons:
- None found yet

For a good (late) V kit or a used H1, the initial costs are similar (£1-2K)
Are H series cameras likely to depreciate more (quickly) than a V?

So which makes more sense as a portrait camera? (I don't intend to buy a mass of lenses or kit, just as a decent film camera).

Comment: Are you actually interested in the _investment_ value, or the _utility_?

Comment: erm..... well both really!
I am not after a work horse / commercial camera so want it to retain value as well as offering the best usage

Answer (score 1):

Cameras and cars retain resale value in the same way: badly. The good news is that second-hand cameras that are already a couple of decades old won't have much farther to drop unless something tragic happens: it breaks or film takes another significant hit to its availability.

Buying new, of course, is a vastly different proposition that involves much higher costs and lower proportionate return if you sell the gear later. The advantage is that it's much more likely to provide trouble-free operation. I have bought one film camera new because I expect it to be a life-long companion, but that's also true of a film SLR that I bought used for a fraction of its original cost. I have also bought and later sold a Hasselblad V-system kit for essentially what I paid for it.

As for utility, either H or V system will produce excellent results, and if you can wear one of those cameras out then you will have achieved so much with it that replacing it would be a trivial concern. And that's true of a number of great cameras, so pick what you'll enjoy and what will let you concentrate on the more important tasks of making photos and creating art.

Answer (score 0):

Don't buy either if you are looking for investment value.  You would do better to put your money in a proper investment vehicle.

In terms of utility, I've owned both (Hasselblad H2, Hasselblad V/500-series and Hasselblad V/203FE) with Phase and Hasselblad digital backs.

Overall, I found the V's unfamiliar ergonomics took some getting used to.  In the end though, it grew on me and I preferred it to the H.

I also found the V glass to be generally more pleasing to my eye than the H's Fuji glass, but remember, V glass is all manual focus.  H glass is optimized for studio work/portraiture, while V is optimized for work at infinity.

It's worth noting that the H does not have a vertical grip(!); so for portrait work you will be holding the (heavy) camera in a vertical position from above.  If shooting 645 with the V, you would simply rotate the film mask to shoot in portrait orientation.

Hope that helps,
Brad

Comment: Thanks Brad (i have actually owned a 500EL briefly, probably should have mentioned that)
Question regarding your last comment - I'm not sure what you mean, as the V backs only mount on one orientation, and its a square frame anyway, so makes no difference??!!

Comment: I've just sold my Rollei 6x6 so perhaps I have projected a Rollei feature onto the Hasselblad platform, but of course you're right about not needing to rotate (if you're shooting 6x6).  I didn't assume that, though, so if you're shooting 645, I do know that the Rollei's allow you to mount it in portrait orientation; The A16 (210) and A32 (220) backs for Hassy V are 645.  I assume they have an equally elegant solution for portrait orientation.  Operating a V sideways would be a nightmare (esp. with a waist level finder).

Comment: Actually Im fairly sure they dont, its 6x6 on the v, and 645 landscape on the H. on the H digital its a smaller frame which puts me off the H3D (which i was offered recently at a VERY good price)

Comment: You can see some here: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/hasselblad-645-back

Comment: yes as i remembered - the advance winder and locking clips only work in the one orientation.